# Why is my database not being updated when someone visits my website?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database

For some reason when a user comes to my site to play multiplayer the call to the php file is sent, but the database never adds a new player or updates their information.

php file is called with the following line of code from a javascript file:

```
xmlhttp.open('GET',"xml_http_request.php?mod0="+truckHeading+"&mod1="+newhtr[1]+"&mod2="+absRoll+"&lla0="+lla[0]+"&lla1="+lla[1]+"&lla2="+lla[2]+"&pid="+rCC+"&rangeCheck="+rangeCheck+"&ranger="+ranger+"&namely="+namely+"&message="+message+"&unLoader=false", true);
```

Here's the php code:

```
<?php
require("db1.php"); //for using live public database
//require("db.php"); //for using local database

$inserter=0;

//assign pid if have not already
$pid=$_GET['pid'];
if($pid=='false'){
  $inserter=1;
  $query="SELECT id FROM positioner";
  $result=mysql_query($query);
  $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($result);
  $i=1;
  while($row=@mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if($i!=$row['id']){ $pid=$i;break; } //take first available id
    $i++;
  }
  if($pid=='false'){ $pid=$num_rows+1; }  //if no hole in id list, take next one higher
  mysql_free_result($result);
}

$unLoader=$_GET['unLoader'];

if($unLoader=='true'){
  $ddb=dbq("DELETE FROM positioner WHERE id = '".$pid."' LIMIT 1;");
}else{

  $dbMi=$_GET['dbMi'];

  $mod0=$_GET['mod0'];
  $mod1=$_GET['mod1'];
  $mod2=$_GET['mod2'];

  $lla0=$_GET['lla0'];
  $lla1=$_GET['lla1'];
  $lla2=$_GET['lla2'];

  $rangeCheck=$_GET['rangeCheck'];
  $namely=addslashes($_GET['namely']);
  if($namely==''){ $namely='x'; }
  $message=addslashes($_GET['message']);

  $rangeCheck='true';
  //only check range every x number of ticks (50, ~3 seconds)?
  // , $rangeCheck is true first time
  if($rangeCheck=='true'){
    $ranger=array();
    //get lat lon of all for determining who is in range
    $query="SELECT id, lla0, lla1 FROM positioner WHERE id != '".$pid."' ";
    $result=mysql_query($query);

    //if distance < 10000, put id in ranger array
    while($row=@mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      //leave rangeCheck off for now
      //$di=dister($row['lla0'],$row['lla1'],$lla0,$lla1);
      //if($di<10000){
      $ranger[]=$row['id'];
    //}
    }
    mysql_free_result($result);
    if(count($ranger)==0){
      $rangerS=''; 
    }else{
      $rangerS=implode(",", $ranger);
    }

    //between rangeChecks get ranger array from js
  }else{
    $rangerS=$_GET['ranger'];  // $rangerS: string(for inserting) 
    $ranger=explode(",",$rangerS); // $ranger: array(for looping)
  }

  //insert new row first time
  if($inserter==1){
    $idb=dbq("INSERT positioner (id,mod0,mod1,mod2,lla0,lla1,lla2,ranger,namely,message,model) 
      VALUES ('".$pid."', '".$mod0."', '".$mod1."', '".$mod2."', '".$lla0."', '".$lla1."', '".$lla2."', '".$rangerS."', '".$namely."', '".$message."', '".$dbMi."');");

  }else{
    //update the database with current model data and result of range check
    $udb=dbq("UPDATE positioner SET mod0 = '".$mod0."', mod1 = '".$mod1."', mod2 = '".$mod2."', lla0 = '".$lla0."', lla1 = '".$lla1."', lla2 = '".$lla2."', ranger = '".$rangerS."', namely = '".$namely."', message = '".$message."', model = '".$dbMi."' WHERE id = '".$pid."' LIMIT 1;");
  }

  header("Content-type: text/xml");
  echo '<markers>';
  echo '<marker ranger="'.$rangerS.'" pid="'.$pid.'" />';

  //loop through a number of times equal to number of id's in ranger array
  foreach($ranger as $rang){
    $query="SELECT mod0, mod1, mod2, lla0, lla1, lla2, namely, message, model FROM positioner WHERE id = '".$rang."' ";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    while ($row=@mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

      echo '<marker mod0="'.$row['mod0'].'" />';       
      echo '<marker mod1="'.$row['mod1'].'" />'; 
      echo '<marker mod2="'.$row['mod2'].'" />'; 
      echo '<marker lla0="'.$row['lla0'].'" />';     
      echo '<marker lla1="'.$row['lla1'].'" />'; 
      echo '<marker lla2="'.$row['lla2'].'" />'; 
      echo '<marker namely="'.rawurlencode(stripslashes($row['namely'])).'" />';
      echo '<marker message="'.rawurlencode(stripslashes($row['message'])).'" />';
      echo '<marker dbMi="'.$row['model'].'" />';  
    }
  }

  echo '</markers>';

} //end if unLoader

//function for calculating distance between latlon pairs, for range check
/* not necessary for only a few visitors
function dister($lat1,$lon1,$lat2,$lon2){
  $R=6378100;
  $lat1*=pi()/180; 
  $lon1*=pi()/180;
  $lat2*=pi()/180; 
  $lon2*=pi()/180;
  $dLat=$lat2-$lat1;
  $dLon=$lon2-$lon1;
  $a=sin($dLat/2)*sin($dLat/2)
    +cos($lat1)*cos($lat2)*
    sin($dLon/2)*sin($dLon/2);
  $c=2*atan2(sqrt($a),sqrt(1-$a));
  $di=$R*$c;
  $di=round($di,6); 
  return $di;        
}
*/
?>
```

Comment: lot of script, lot of possibilities, your going to have to do some basic debugging for yourself

Comment: There's also a SQL injection vulnerability in there.  The fact that your database is _not_ being updated is a stroke of very good luck.

Comment: I see at least two `@` error-silencing operators in there.  Get rid of them, then place these two statements at the very top of the script and try visiting it again: `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(-1);`  If you don't see errors, I'll be quite surprised.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some notes.

- The "assign pid if have not already" block is tragic.  You're grabbing the entire contents of the table, and then row-by-row checking to see if you found the right one.  The code *blindly assumes* that the row count is going to match the id column when picking what the next `pid` should be.  The proper thing to do (for MySQL) would be using an auto-increment column so that you don't need to worry about that mess.
- Your `DELETE FROM` query contains an [**SQL Injection vulnerability**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  If `pid` is not the string `'false'`, it will never be validated.  Someone can destroy the entire `positioner` table.  How do you protect against it?  Well...
- You're using `addslashes`.  This isn't a code *smell*, it's a code *stench*.  `addslashes` has never, ever at any time in the entire history of computing been the correct thing to use*.  I think you're looking for a *real* database escaping mechanism.  Because you're using the atrocious "mysql" interface, you want [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).
- `lla1` and `lla2`?  Those are the best and most descriptive names for columns you could come up with?  I'm going to assume those are latitude/longitude pairs.
- Once again, you have SQL injection in that `SELECT`.
- And in that `INSERT`, you are possibly blindly trusting `$rangerS`.  SQL Injection ahoy!
- And in the `UPDATE`.
- I'd also like to rant briefly about string `'true'` and string `'false'`, but those are coming from bad Javascript.  Consider having them submitted as `1` and `0` instead.  Also, please, please consider using a modern Javascript library like jQuery instead of rolling your own Ajax bits.  It will save you time and stress.

**I *think* the core problem here is actually the initial `pid` check.**  I'm going to bet that you're always getting a new or incorrect `pid` back from the table, because the `id` is unlikely to perfectly match the row count.  Then you're doing a blind no-error-check `INSERT` with the "new" `pid`, but if your indexes are designed properly, this will fail with a duplicate key error.  Therefore, no updates.  **But this is just speculation.**  Other than the vulnerabilities here, I'm not sure I completely understand what's happening, and I'm not spotting anything obviously incorrect.

There's another possible problem here.  I'm going to assume that `pid` means *player ID* from the context.  Your code is *blindly* trusting that the request is coming from the player that *owns* that `pid`, but *anyone* can just make a request here with *any* valid `pid` and make moves for people as a result.  I'm not sure you intended that.

<sup>* Okay, maybe someone found `addslashes` useful once or twice...</sup>

Comment: @Pointy: Glad to provide the entertainment value.  I've since clarified my speculation on the core problem, but we'll need to know more about the database to be sure.  I *somehow* expect that we'll never know.

Comment: it's hard to judge attitude from brief online written messages, but I assure you that I was serious and not sarcastic at all. I voted up and wish I could do so 10 times. This is the sort of answer that makes this site valuable.

Comment: @Pointy, no sarcasm assumed!  While this might be the type of answer that makes SO valuable, the way this question was asked occasionally makes me want to nuke the site from orbit.  I figured that at least exerting an effort on an interesting problem might be worth it!